# How can make Getter or Setter Property in Class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set my property just getter that's means the user can just get not setting into property

this Apple Library Code Id like this code

```swift
 open var imageView: UIImageView? { get } // default is nil.  image view will be created if necessary.


    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    open var textLabel: UILabel? { get } // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary.

    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    open var detailTextLabel: UILabel? { get } // default is nil.  label will be created if necessary (and the current style supports a detail label).


    // If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.
    open var contentView: UIView { get }
```

Comment: You can read about properties, `getter` and `setters` here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

What do you want to achieve? Do you wanna create some views programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

`private(set) var foo: Int = 0`

Now only the `getter` is public

Answer (score 0):

if you make it a constant property no one will be able to modify it :

```
var someProperty = 10
let constantProperty = 10

someProperty = 15
//all good, var has setter and getter
constantProperty = 15
//error : Cannot assign to value: 'constantProperty' is a 'let' constant because let has only getter
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like following

```
class myClass{
private var _myInt: Int = 10
public var myVar: Int {
    get {
        return _myInt
    }
}
public func changeint(_ newval: Int) {
    _myInt = newval
}
}
```

and simply use it :

```
var newclass = myClass()

print("\(newclass.myVar)")
newclass.changeint(12)
print("\(newclass.myVar)")
```